# How to grep man pages for a word?

Tags: search, man

Recently I wanted to get info of `struct timespec` a field of `lstat` structure, but I couldn't get any. I tried

```
$ man timespec
$ man -k timespec
 timespec: nothing appropriate.
```

After some time I went through man page of `clock_gettime` for unrelated query and there I got to know the structure of `timespec`. But this was accidentally. So `timespec` word was present in man page of `clock_gettime` but I was not able to search it.

So, I would like to know, how to search for a word in all manpages? or do a grep kind of search? Any hints?

Comment: Tangential to your actual question, but in case it's helpful: /usr/include has system header files that you can easily grep.

Comment: If someone else is wondering, See my post on ask-Ubuntu:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1281432/how-to-use-grep-to-search-for-options-in-a-man-page/1281435#1281435 (External link added)

Answer (score 7):

I normally fall back to google in such circumstances but try using `man -K`.

From the man man page:

> -k, --apropos
>
>   Equivalent to apropos.  Search the short manual page descriptions for keywords and display any matches.  See apropos(1) for details.
>
> -K, --global-apropos
>
>   Search for text in all manual pages.  This is a brute-force search, and is likely to take some time; if you can, you should specify a section to reduce the number of pages that need to be searched.  Search terms may be simple strings (the default), or regular expressions if the --regex option is used.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Peter.O, I'll try to wean my addiction to code tags!

Answer (score 1):

`apropos timespec`.

That will search through all the man pages for "timespec".

Comment: apropos is just an alias for man -k